# Hiding and creating another object on clicking tabbed items - HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple page where when I click on one tabbed item should let display disappear for that page. In this simple code, when I click on About should let product dropdown menu disappear. Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Drop Down Navbar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <h3>Bootstrap Dropdown Menu By Creativity-Tuts</h3>
                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Prod 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Prod 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Prod 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Prod 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I going use onClick and call a function to hide that drop down menu? Here is the jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/KUYX7/)

Comment: Can you post the entire code with CSS and JS?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uQApiJ/2/ The whol container with month as the dropdown menu should disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add id to «about» link, then use such code:

```
$('#about').click(function(){
  $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
});
```

Comment: Can u check the comment over my question? I just updated Thank you

Comment: Could you please explain again your goal?

Comment: Got it working thank you
I'm trying to access the tab feature by hiding one container and displaying the other.